# Return image from HTTP Post request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, xmlhttprequest, put

I send data from a browser to a servlet using JavaScript, then the server processes the data and returns an image as a response (all using xmlhttprequest). I'm sure everything is working fine because when I call the server directly, I get my image back in the browser.

What I was wondering is how, in JavaScript, do I parse my response so that I can display it as an image in an img tag?

I figure this should be fairly easy, but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and set the base64 encoded binary data as the `src` for an image tag.

If you have control over the server, it might be cleaner to have the server give you a URL you can refer to and create a new `img` tag with that `src`.

Comment: Ended up using this method. Just make sure your content-length is size of your base64 encoded binary data and not your image byte size (that tripped me up for awhile).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work with your application, but you could use a server-side script to dynamically serve an image, and then just use javascript to change the source of your image.

i.e.

```
src="image.php?param1=XXXX&param2=XXXX"
```

Or just have your `XMLHttpRequest` return a new path to an existing image on the server and then just change the `src` attribute of your `img`.

Comment: This is not HTTP POST.